# mongodb aggregate, filtering inner array of objects

Tags: mongodb, filter, aggregate

I have mongo v 3.2
I need filtering inner array of objects. But filter not work.

I have object

```
{
   _id: "112233",
   mainOptions: {
     option0: "op0",
     option1: "op1",
     option2: "op2"
   },
   instructions: [
     0: {
      number: 0,
      header: {
        desc: "d0",
        inst: "i0"
      }
      items: [
       0: {
         info: {
           text: "one info"
         }
       }
       1: {
         info: {
           text: "two info"
         }
       }
      ]
     }
     1: {
      number: 1,
      header: {
        desc: "d1",
        inst: "i1"
      }
      items: [
       0: {
         info: {
           text: "one info"
         }
       }
       1: {
         info: {
           text: "two info"
         }
       }
      ]
     }
   ]
}
```

How can i return object with all structure, but in "items" I need leave only item where info.text = "two info"

I try to use:

```
db.onlineBallots.aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$match" : {
                "_id": "112233", 
                "mainOptions.option0" : "op0"
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "mainOptions" : 1, 
                "instructions.items" : {
                    "$filter" : {
                        "input" : "$instructions.items", 
                        "as" : "item", 
                        "cond" : { "$regex": "two", "$options": "i" } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
);
```

But filter not work. I receive all items in "items".
Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: There is still no "logical" `$regex` operator for use with aggregation logical conditions. You can only use that operator within a `$match`, which means using `$unwind` and not `$filter`.

Comment: How can I do this? Please help me to write a aggregation query. I try to use $match and $unwind, but I receive blank list only.

Comment: I have helped you by pointing you at the example that shows you how to do it. Note that the full path to the values you are looking for is actually `"instructions.items.info.text"` and you will need to `$unwind` both `"$instructions"` and `"$instructions.items"`

Comment: I create two $unwind - "$instructions" and "$instructions.items". I got one complete object for each item. But I need one object with items which are the same as the string "two". What I need to do after this?